# Is it proper form to use capital letters for constant variables in Python?

Tags: python, code-formatting

Which is the correct way to declare constants in Python:

```
MAX_FILESIZE = 10000
```

or

```
max_filesize = 10000
```

Answer (score 8):

PEP 0008, the official style guide for Python, has a section on this [here](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants):

> Constants
>
> Constants are usually defined on a module level and written in all
> capital letters with underscores separating words. Examples include
> `MAX_OVERFLOW` and `TOTAL`.

So, the first example is correct.